# Image does not show in HTML formate in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have used like bellow code to show an image but image is not showing.

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
<body>\
      <tr>\
         <td>\
           <img src=\"images/a.png\" />\  // a.png is under Resources/images folder
         </td>\
       </tr>\ 
       <tr>\
         <td>\
           hello\
         </td>\
       </tr>\
</body>\
</html>"];
[wView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

but image is not showing by using above code.

Answer (score 3):

Try like below and edit properly then you will get:

```
NSString *boy_imageString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"png"];
    boy_imageString = [boy_imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
    boy_imageString = [ boy_imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    boy_imageString = [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:boy_imageString];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
                <body>\
                               <tr>\
                                 <td>\
                                    <img src=\"%@" />\  // a.png is under Resources/images folder
                                 </td>\
                               </tr>\ 
                               <tr>\
                                  <td>\
                                     hello\
                                   </td>\
                               </tr>\
                           </body>\
            </html>/",boy_imageString];
        [wView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Use NSURL instead of NSString. And use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` instead of doing it manually.